# Django model filter: needs to filter two columns

Tags: django, orm

So I have this model Game that has an Awayteam and Hometeam field. Now I want to get all the games of a certain club. So I need to get all objects in which my club is an away team or a hometeam.

I could do: 
`Game.object.filter(hometeam=myteam)` and a a seperate `Game.object.filter(awayteam=myteam)` query.
However, can I combine these queries into one with django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for "OR" queries, you want to have a look at [`Q objects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)